# Problema al conectar servidor socket.io con backend en AWS

Tags: nodejs, aws, nginx, socket.io, angular8

Tengo una aplicación funcionando en AWS, pero le incorpore un chat con socket.io y no logro que socket.io se conecte al backend que tengo subido en AWS.  Gracias de antemano, llevo días con esto.

DNS de IPv4 pública:
ec2-1-1?8-x1?-x0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Este es el archivo de configuracion que une al servidor NGINX con el backend node js:

```js
server {
  charset utf-8;
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;

  # angular app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/front-end;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

Esta la conexión de socket.io desde el front :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { apiUrl } from '../api'
@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
  
  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  readonly URL_API= '/api';

  private socket = io(this.URL_API, {'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});
  
   joinRoom(data) {
    console.log("DATA : ", data);
    this.socket.emit('join', data);
  }
  
}
```

Y este es el archivo que se comunica con el servidor de NGINX en AWS:

```js
var express=require('express');
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var {database} =require('./keys');
var config=require('./config');
var app =config(express()); 
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var morgan=require('morgan');
var cors=require('cors');

server.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port',app.get('port'));
});

//Funciones
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json()); // Reconocer el formato JSON 


app.use(cors({origin:'ec2-1-1?8-x1?-x0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com'}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "ec2-1-1?8-x1?-x0.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Comment: Lo que estás armando en socket.io dónde lo pones a correr? Le estás llegando a la EC2 por la IP privada y pa eso toca asumir que todo está en la misma VPC o hay configuración del security group y toda la cosa... o toca ponerle una IP pública a la EC2 y asegurarla. No es claro

Comment: El socket.io Corre en el mismo servidor del backend que esta en el mismo ec2 que el front.  Lo estoy conectando por medio de la IP publica aun.